# Real Time Interactive Queries IN HADOOP

Tags: hadoop, hive, real-time

Is it possible to do realtime interactive queries in hadoop?

When I use Hive over YARN/tez the latency is still too high, even when it's over parquet/ocr.

Any suggestion?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is not a good choice for realtime or near-realtime queries. The latency overhead of running anything in Hadoop would be high. Consider using Apache Spark (Since I expect that you have a batch processing system, as you are using Hadoop). Spark provides interactive queries using spark shell. You can also use Impala to do queries on data stored in HDFS. Impala, I believe, provides faster queries compared to Hive.

Comment: of course, or using hive on spark, but the real problem is that hive on spark is still in developement branch, same for impala it's can have concurency over 50 users...so for production mode it's not really the best choices

Comment: Consider using Apache spark directly? Or Spark Shell for interactive queries, depending on your goals.

Comment: yeah it's a solution but most of companies still want to use their traditional systems like Hive, or other software like tableau